# Worklight 6.1 Android ant build not using shell template configChanges

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I was having a problem that all android apps build with 6.1 and ant were closing on rotate.
When i notices that the AndroidManifest.xml was not including the changeConfig screenSize.

When i look at my AndroidManifest.xml.wltemplate.wluser i see clearly

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Yet after ant build doing an ant build i see this in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Other configurations(packageName, minApiVersion) made in the wluser template are being used.

My build command looks like::

```
<app-builder applicationFolder="${appPath}/${appName}" environments="android" 
            nativeProjectPrefix="${appName}" outputFolder="./bin" 
            skinBuildExtensions="build-dojo.xml" worklightserverhost="${wlServerAddress}"/>
```

Is there something im missing, this worked in 505.
Worklight Ant Task version 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630

Comment: I tried to build an empty app in 6.1 GM with Dojo  using ant and the build.xml you supplied, 
The android manifest looks fine and the app works.
Have you tried to build it using eclipse?

It might happen because you use a non formal version of Worklight

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of making changes in AndroidManifest.xml.wltemplate.wluser

Add your changes to AndroidManifest.xml which exists in nativeEmptyApp folder if you are using inner application.

or

If you dont have inner application add your changes in AndroidManifest.xml which exists in nativeResources in Android project.

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !!